# WebAPI returning invalid response for BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple API.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("problem")]
public ActionResult Prob()
{
    _logger.Debug($"HealthController.Accept");

    return Problem("WTF?", statusCode: (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

When I call it with Postman, I get the following:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "WTF?",
    "traceId": "00-597a16e01489876a399d2e10e02789f7-20900f8e949848ac-00"
}BadRequest
```

I am expecting just this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "WTF?",
    "traceId": "00-597a16e01489876a399d2e10e02789f7-20900f8e949848ac-00"
}
```

How can I remove the `BadRequest` part that is getting concatenated to the response?

**UPDATE**
A comment suggested it may be a Middleware. From Startup.cs I noticed this `app.UseErrorHandling();`:

```
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        // app.UseErrorHandling();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(ep => { ep.MapControllers(); });
```

After commenting this out, the response is as expected.  Thank you
@nikstra for the suggestion. In a shared library, I had built a handler for handling custom Authorization errors, and completely forgot about it.

Comment: return Problem(..) What is the Problem? Can you post the code pls?

Comment: I copied your action to a .Net 6 Web API project and I can't reproduce. What version are you running? Do you have any middleware registered that may mess with the response?

Comment: Seems like it might be coming from postman (although that seems strange). Nothing obvious in the code would be adding that data. Yes as @nikstra said, could also be some type of middleware adding details to the response.

Comment: % dotnet --version
6.0.405.  (dotnetcore)

Comment: It is not just Postman... it appears in my app when returning API calls that throw an error. I wanted to show an error from the API, but always the error message would have "WTF?.BadRequest". I tried returning Problem, instead of BadRequest("WTF?"), same result.  To verify, I used Postman to ensure it wasn't React/Axios.

Comment: Make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are returning a BadRequest result with a parameter statusCode set to 400, which causes the server to set the status description to "BadRequest".

You can try creating custom problem detail object which includes custom 'Title' property that does not include the word "Bad Request"

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("problem")]
public ActionResult Prob()
{
    _logger.Debug($"HealthController.Accept");

    var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
    {
        Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
        Title = "WTF?",
        Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
        Detail = "Something went wrong",
        Instance = HttpContext.TraceIdentifier
    };

    return BadRequest(problemDetails);
}
```

Now, this would use the custom object instead of default "BadRequest" value.

result would be,

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "WTF?",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Something went wrong",
    "instance": "traceId"
}
```